# Xamarin test recorder

Tags: xamarin

I am interested in writing automated scripts for Xamarin mobile apps.
I installed Xamarin Studio, VS 2015 Enterprise, Gtk# 2.12.22, Xamarin test recorder on my windows 8 laptop.

I could run the app using Android emulator and also can test some of the sample tests in the test cloud.

When I am trying to use the Xamarin test recorder, it is not producing the code when I run the app and perform some actions. Permission is also INTERNET in the Android manifest file.

How to make it work?

Comment: Assuming you have followed the instructions found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/visual-studio/?

Answer (score 0):

According to the XTC Tutorial (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/visual-studio/), you need to have the following

1. Have a device/emulator connected,
2. UI Test project,
3. Have a `TestFixture` class
4. Click the lightning bolt icon and hit *Record New Test*
5. Select the APK found in your bin folder
6. Once its fully connected, any interaction will be recorded

To stop, you would click stop recording in your test class.

Comment: I have everything set up as you have mentioned above. And following all the instructions from the documentation from the link above. Still no luck.